# Parsing XML into a dictionary of lists Python/Django

Tags: python, xml, django, dictionary

I'm having a little issue with parsing an xml with python. I'm trying to get my dictionary to look like the following

```
listDict = [{'name':'Sales','id':'1','position':'1','order_by_type':'True','order_by_asc':'True;}, {'name':'Information','id':'2','position':'1','order_by_type':'True','order_by_asc':'True;}]
```

I'm thinking my loop after pulling data from the xml string is wrong.

```
        xml_data = ElementTree.fromstring(self.data)
    # Lets grab all the base cats info and add them to a dict containing a list
    base_cats = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/Name')
    base_cats_id = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/base_id')
    base_postion = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/position')
    base_order_by_type = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_type')
    base_order_by_asc = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_asc')

    # store all information into lists
    base_cat = [t.text for t in base_cats]
    base_id = [t.text for t in base_cats_id]
    base_p = [t.text for t in base_postion]
    base_obt = [t.text for t in base_order_by_type]
    base_asc = [t.text for t in base_order_by_asc]

    base_dict = defaultdict(list)
    # lets put everything in the list into a dictionary
    for base in range(len(base_cat)):  # for each base in base_cat loop
        base_dict[base].append(base_cat[base])
        base_dict[base].append(base_id[base])
        base_dict[base].append(base_p[base])
        base_dict[base].append(base_obt[base])
        base_dict[base].append(base_asc[base])
```

This produces the following.

```
instance = {0: ['Sales 2', '1', '10', 'True', 'True'], 1: ['Information 2', '2', '20', 'True', 'True'], 2: ['Listing 2', '3', '30', 'True', 'True'], 3: ['Information', '4', '40', 'True', 'True'], 4: ['Land', '5', '50', 'True', 'True'], 5: ['&', '6', '60', 'True', 'True'], 6: ['Tax', '7', '70', 'True', 'True'], 7: ['Construction', '9', '90', 'True', 'True'], 8: ['Interior/Utilites', '10', '100', 'True', 'True'], 9: ['HOA/Community', '11', '110', 'True', 'True'], 10: ['Remarks', '12', '120', 'True', 'True'], 11: ['Exterior', '8', '80', 'True', 'True']})
```

My end goal is to be able to do the following on my django template

```
{%for item in instance%}
{{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help on how I may have something wrong would help a lot. Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:
As asked here is the xml I have.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FormInstance>
    <BaseCategory>
        <Name>Sales</Name>
        <base_id>1</base_id>
        <position>10</position>
        <order_by_type>True</order_by_type>
        <order_by_asc>True</order_by_asc>
    </BaseCategory>
    <BaseCategory>
        <Name>Information</Name>
        <base_id>2</base_id>
        <position>20</position>
        <order_by_type>True</order_by_type>
        <order_by_asc>True</order_by_asc>
        <MainCategory>
            <main_id>1</main_id>
            <Name>Address 3</Name>
            <is_visible>True</is_visible>
            <position>10</position>
            <order_by_type>True</order_by_type>
            <order_by_asc>True</order_by_asc>
            <SubCategory>
                <sub_id>1</sub_id>
                <Name>Street Number 2</Name>
                <sub_library_id>StreetNumber</sub_library_id>
                <field_display_type>[u'input']</field_display_type>
                <field_type>[u'varchar']</field_type>
                <is_active>True</is_active>
                <is_required>True</is_required>
                <help_text>Street Number</help_text>
                <main_category>1</main_category>
                <is_visible>True</is_visible>
                <position>10</position>
                <order_by_type>True</order_by_type>
                <order_by_asc>True</order_by_asc>
                <show_seller>True</show_seller>
                <Enumerations>
                    <enum_id>4</enum_id>
                    <Name>Test Enum</Name>
                    <library_id>test enum</library_id>
                    <is_active>True</is_active>
                    <sub_category>1</sub_category>
                    <is_visible>True</is_visible>
                    <position>10</position>
                    <order_by_type>True</order_by_type>
                    <order_by_asc>True</order_by_asc>
                </Enumerations>
            </SubCategory>
        </MainCategory>
    </BaseCategory>
</FormInstance>
```

Comment: How does the XML look like? For what I gathered, it looks like you'd be better off iterating over the `BaseCategory` items and getting its subnodes?

Comment: @BorrajaX I've added in the xml. Sorry for not adding it in the original post.

Comment: No worries :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for what I gather in the expected results, it looks like you just want to get the information about nodes that are strictly `BaseCategory`, right? In the XML that was provided in the *edit*, you have two of those.

You should see the XML as a tree of nodes. In the example, you have something like:

```
                     FormInstance  # this is the root
                      /         \
                     /           \
             BaseCategory       BaseCategory
             (name:Sales)    (name:Information)
                                    \
                                     \
                                  MainCategory
                                (name:Address 3)
                                        \
                                         \
                                      Subcategory
                                  (name:Street Number 2)
```

But you only need the information in the `BaseCategory` elements, right?

You could just position yourself in the `root` (which... well... is what [`xml.fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) does anyway) iterate over its `BaseCategory` nodes, get the items you need from those `BaseCategory` nodes and put them in your list of dictionaries.

Something like:

```
import pprint
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open("sample_xml.xml", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    xml_data = ElementTree.fromstring(data)

base_categories = xml_data.findall("./BaseCategory")
print("Found %s base_categories." % len(base_categories))
list_dict = []
for base_category in base_categories:
    list_dict.append({
        "name": base_category.find("Name").text,
        "id": int(base_category.find("base_id").text),
        "position": int(base_category.find("position").text),
        "order_by_type": (True if base_category.find("order_by_type").text.lower() == "true"
                          else False),
        "order_by_asc": (True if base_category.find("order_by_asc").text.lower() == "true"
                         else False),
    })

print("list_dict=%s" % (pprint.pformat(list_dict)))
```

Which outputs:

```
Found 2 base_categories.
list_dict=[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'Sales',
  'order_by_asc': True,
  'order_by_type': True,
  'position': 10},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'Information',
  'order_by_asc': True,
  'order_by_type': True,
  'position': 20}]
```

The idea is that a `BaseCategory` item is something that can be seen as a self-contained record (like a *dict*, if it helps you see it) that can contain (in it) the following attributes:

- A string with the name in `Name`
- A numeric id in `base_id`
- A numeric `position`
- A boolean `order_by_type`
- A boolean `order_by_asc`
- Another object `MainCategory` with its own fields...

So every time you position yourself in one of these `BaseCategory` nodes, you just gather the interesting fields that it has and put them in dictionaries.

When you do:

```
base_cats = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/Name')
base_cats_id = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/base_id')
base_postion = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/position')
base_order_by_type = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_type')
base_order_by_asc = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_asc')
```

You are treating those element (`base_id`, `position`...) almost as independent elements, which is not exactly what you have in your XML.

However, if you are absolutely **certain** that all those lists (`base_cats`, `base_cats_id`, `base_position`...) do contain the same number of items, you can still re-build your dictionary, using the lenght of one of them (in the example below `len(base_cats)`, but it could've been `len(base_cats_id)`, `len(base_position)`... since all those lists have the same length) to iterate through all the lists in the same step:

```
base_cats = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/Name')
base_cats_id = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/base_id')
base_postion = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/position')
base_order_by_type = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_type')
base_order_by_asc = xml_data.findall('./BaseCategory/order_by_asc')

list_dict = []
for i in range(len(base_cats)):
    list_dict.append({
        "name": base_cats[i].text,
        "id": int(base_cats_id[i].text),
        "position": int(base_postion[i].text),
        "order_by_type": True if base_order_by_type[i].text.lower() == "true" else False,
        "order_by_asc": True if base_order_by_asc[i].text.lower() == "true" else False,
    })
print("list_dict=%s" % (pprint.pformat(list_dict)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help BorrajaX. This helps me a lot and able to understand it better. Eventually I will need Main, Sub and Enum. Though with your answer, I believe I'll be able to adapt it to my needs. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: When you have to do that, you just need to see that your base category also contains a dict (or "object") `MainCategory`, which has a bunch of "fields" (`name`, `base_id`...) which can subsequently contain a `SubCategory` field that is a dict (or "object") with another bunch of "fields"... and so on **:-)** Have fun coding!

Comment: Thanks again BorrajaX. I've been stuck on this for two days and finally gave in to ask. Appreciate your help!